# How can I connect ( and if required isolate a single module ) multiple LI-ion battery modules(with different SOCs) in parallel sharing common load

Tags: dc-dc-converter, lithium-ion, protection, battery-operated, efficiency

1.Need to connect two or more Li ion battery modules(having different SOC levels)  in parallel with the help of bidirectional dc-dc converters sharing a common load(say 48V).
2.Isolating individual modules of very low SOC from the parallel connection if required without disturbing the operation of the other modules.

Currently progress:

1. we are using parallel ganged batteries(of 14S,18650 battery modules) dual bus configuration for our application
   2.Isolating the total pack from the load if one of the modules have low SOC

Comment: If the cells just have power coming out of them, you could simply use a diode from each cell. Or you could do it (in a better fashion) with a BMS per cell, which would also protect each cell from over-discharge. However, you shouldn't be putting battery cells with differen SOCs together, why are you doing that?

Comment: Actually we are isolating all the parallelly connected modules whenever the tiny BMS detects the SOC of any one module to be significantly low ,in order to reduce the state of abuse of the modules. After isolation,we are removing the module with low SOC and replacing it with  a new module of higher SOC without changing the rest of the modules in parallel(so these modules have different SOC in comparison to the new module ).Thats the reason why included putting modules of differnt  SOCs in the question  .